# How to automatically update on localhost after editing files

Tags: updates, localhost

I'm just starting with learning wordpress and wondering if there's a way if I can have my page in the browser (on a localhost using WAMP) automatically update after I make updates to the theme's code and save them using a text editor or if I will have to re-zip and re-upload every time I want to view the changes I'm making.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: How are you making the changes? If you have an install on WAMP, just edit the code in place and refresh the page.

Comment: Uploading the files will only replace the files with themselves, it's a none-operation

Answer (score 2):

Use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com) + [Gulp-Watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) + [BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io).

The goal is to run an extra process that monitors any changes in your files. When a change occurs the page is **automatically** reloaded including CSS injection / Scrolls / Browser clicks and all concurrently across multiple devices and browsers. Because it also generates an ip:port you can access the link from other devices in your network.

This [gulpfile.js task](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L240-L260) is based on the [roots.io](https://roots.io) - [Sage theme](https://roots.io/sage/).

---

```
var $           = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
```

---

```
gulp.task('watch-local.dev', function() { 
  init_watch ( false, 3001, { target: 'http://local.dev' } ); 
});
```

---

This breakout function allows you to create tasks per environment including; [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/), [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [Docker](https://www.docker.com) and [Vagrant](https://github.com/ideasonpurpose/basic-wordpress-vagrant) & toggle `http` / `https` individually. Note:  `local.dev` is a byproduct of [Vagrant Host Manager](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager).

```
function init_watch (https, port, proxy) {

    var defaults = {
        port: 3001,
        https: true,
        proxy: config.devUrl // { target: 'http://your-expected-site-name.com' }
    };

    if( typeof https !== 'boolean') { https = defaults.https; }
    if( typeof port !== 'number') { port = defaults.port; }
    if( typeof proxy === 'string') { proxy = { target: proxy }; } // fix the format if only target is passed
    if( typeof proxy !== 'object') { proxy = defaults.proxy; }

    browserSync({
        proxy: proxy,
        https: https,
        port: port,
        snippetOptions: {
            whitelist: ['/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'],
            blacklist: ['/wp-admin/**']
        }
    });

    gulp.watch([path.source + 'styles/**/*'], ['styles']);
    gulp.watch([path.source + 'scripts/**/*'], ['jshint', 'scripts']);
    gulp.watch([path.source + 'fonts/**/*'], ['fonts']);
    gulp.watch([path.source + 'images/**/*'], ['images']);
    gulp.watch(['bower.json', 'assets/manifest.json'], ['build']);
    gulp.watch('**/*.php', function() {
        browserSync.reload();
    });
}
```

---

To execute this task you'll need to run the following command. There are also ways to initiate the gulp task from an IDE including; [PHPStorm / WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-gulp-task-runner.html), [Atom.io](https://atom.io/packages/gulp-control) and [Sublime](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Gulp).

```
gulp watch-local.dev
```

---

It's worth mentioning that the proxy generally works well unless you're browsing the admin portion of your site.

You'll also need [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the [npm command-line tool](https://www.npmjs.com) is bundled with it.

*If you need to deploy the content you can add a task to [FTP](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp) files on change.*